# Doctrine Class Table Inheritance and property ignoral

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I originally posted this question here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/297

I have the following entity hierarchy, **MyProduct** being a parent entity mapped through class table inheritance :

```
SyliusProduct    # Mapped superclass containing the 'options' association mapping
–- MyProduct     # Mapped superclass that should override the association (Head of CTI)
---- MyProduct1  # Ultimate children (entities)
---- MyProduct2
---- MyProduct3
---- MyProduct4
```

**SyliusProduct** has a many-to-many association to an **Option** entity, which is mapped in **SyliusProduct**'s mapping.

I can't change the mapping of **SyliusProduct** (it's part of a Symfony vendor).

When generating the schema, doctrine wants to generate **sylius_product_options** tables for each ultimate child, which throws a 'tables exists' exception.

Is there a way to either:

- map the association at ultimate child level by creating 4 different
  tables (and specify different table names)?
- map it at **MyProduct** level?
- simply ignore the association?

Comment: Are you creating a new entity for each product?

Comment: Yes, MyProduct[1,2,3,4] are entities that extend MyProduct.

Comment: Your problem is that the `Product` entity/table is supposed to contain all of your products in the same entity/table rather than a single product in each.

Comment: Yes, that's right and my question is "Is it possible to store sub-products by using class table inheritance while keeping the 'options' association at MyProduct level?"

Comment: It seems to me the you are looking at the database in the wrong way. Why is it that you are needing to store each of the products in an individual entity rather than storing them all in a single table? What would happen if you wanted to add another product down the line, would you then need to create another entity and change the inheritance to go with it?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but you should set you product entity inheritance-type as single table (do not set the table property of the child entity or you will get an error saying the table already exists)

You also need to add a discriminator map to the MyProduct entity for each subproduct, like so :

```
<entity name="MyProduct" inheritance-type="SINGLE_TABLE">
    <discriminator-map>
        <discriminator-mapping value="pr1" class="MyProduct1"/>
        <discriminator-mapping value="pr2" class="MyProduct2"/>
        <discriminator-mapping value="pr2" class="MyProduct3"/>
    </discriminator-map>
    ...
</entity>
```

If the parent mapped superclass already have the many-to-many option mapping you should not have to redefine it in your MyProduct entity.

This way the MyProduct1-4 entities will inherit from MyProduct which itself inherits from SyliusProduct all on a SINGLE_TABLE so doctrine won't try to create different tables with the same name for each SubProduct.